# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI images/27567f904a64ba79ae95672e4ddf10c8.png

Tags: flutter, networkimageview

I want to retrieve the images from an api and I get this error. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.
Note that I am on the localhost

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: AppConstants.BASE_URL +
        getCartHistoryList[listCounter - 1].img!,
),
```

Comment: Can you tell us the value of AppConstants .BASE_URL? The error message tells you that your URL is not complete. It should start with something like https://...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are trying to fetch image using

> CachedNetworkImage

which will takes

> imageUrl

argument as a String and in

> https://

format i.e. it should be a link
Now come to the error part where error show

> images/27567... so on

which is not the url link so first print this

```
AppConstants.BASE_URL +
        getCartHistoryList[listCounter - 1].img!,
```

and you will get to know the reason and will solve that easily